# Rails 4 Active Record ordering lost on subsequent method calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ancestry

When I retrieve an ordered active records relation, subsequent method calls on that relation do not maintain the order. For example:

```
nodes = post.subtree(:to_depth => 1).order(score: :desc).limit(6)
child_ids = nodes.ids
```

I would expect child_ids to be an array of ids ordered in the same manner that nodes is ordered in (score/ascending). This is not the case. Likewise, when I call

```
nodes.arrange
```

using the ancestry gem, what I get back is not ordered. Is that how it's supposed to behave?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
nodes = post.subtree(:to_depth => 1).order('score DESC').limit(6)
```